# Nginx dockerization port forward

Tags: docker, nginx

I have nginx on my local machine that redirects all http traffic from **port 80 to 8008** with this simple config:

```
server {

    listen 8008;

#        location some-location {
#        
#        }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:80/index.php/;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Everything works OK locally, but I want to place that nginx inside a docker container. My Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 8008 80
```

But when I run my image with cmd

```
docker run -d -p 8008:80 <image ID>
```

Nothing happens, the container stops. Logs here:

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES 2f2602efc455 a58e81b31db6 "nginx -g 'daemon of…" 10 seconds ago Exited (1) 10 seconds ago unruffled_galileo 


docker logs
2018/01/03 12:17:08 [emerg] 1#1: "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1 nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Be so kind and show logs from container runtime. `docker ps -a` and `docker logs <container-id>` commands might be helpful.

Comment: docker ps -a
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
    2f2602efc455        a58e81b31db6        "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   10 seconds ago      Exited (1) 10 seconds ago                       unruffled_galileo

Comment: docker logs 2018/01/03 12:17:08 [emerg] 1#1: "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

Comment: Maybe not the main issue, but are you trying to expose port 8008 _and_ 80? You only have to define which port you want to expose. The mapping is then done in your `docker run` call.

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally I found the error in my nginx.conf:
    user  nginx;
    worker_processes  1;

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

      server {

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:80/index.php/;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                   }
             }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 8008
```

And launched the image with command:

```
docker run -d -p 8008:80 <ID>
```